# Managing incremental schema updates in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite for a few small projects and I've run into an issue today that is easily solved using other SQL databases but apparently it's a major stumbling block here.

Typically, we manage schema updates using a separate file for each update...

```
setup.001.sql
setup.002.sql
...
setup.011.sql
etc.
```

Through the use of various if statements, we can check if certain schema updates need to be performed within the SQL scripts themselves such that it's simply a matter of executing each script in order to bring any version of the database to the current version.

So I've found a couple of issues with this in SQLite:

- There does not appear to be an `if` statement
- There does not appear to be a clean way to retrieve `PRAGMA user_version` into a local variable for checking

How then, does one execute updates dependent on this information internally within a SQL Script? I do not want to have to code a separate update script in another language just to be able to run these scripts conditionally. This seems like a pretty basic need for any database provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database; it is designed to be used together with a 'real' programming language. You have to put the logic into your own application.

The output of `PRAGMA user_version` can be read like the output of any other query.